# Connecting to a local server with Android

Tags: android, mysql, sockets, server

I state that I am not a newcomer to Android programming.

I can not connect to a server, the code I get this error:
Required java.net.Socket found java.lang.Object

This is the code so you can figure out what to do:

Then I press the button for the connection:

```
private void RegistraTerminale() {
    new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.configurazioni_dialog_registra_titolo)
            .setMessage(R.string.configurazioni_dialog_registra_messaggio)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.configurazioni_dialog_registra_si, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pd = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                            .title(R.string.configurazioni_progress_dialog_registra_titolo)
                            .content(R.string.configurazioni_progress_dialog_registra_content)
                            .progress(true, 0)
                            .show();
                    new SincTask().execute(new String[]{_androidId});
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.configurazioni_dialog_registra_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

By agreeing to launch the class SincTask :

```
private class SincTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, genericresult> {
        private SincTask() {
        }

        protected genericresult doInBackground(String... params) {
            genericresult Ret = new genericresult(0, null, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
            try {
                String datiXml = params[0].replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').trim();
                String ipServer = BuildConfig.FLAVOR;
                int PortaServer = 0;
                Cursor c = ConnessioneAlServer.getAllServer(db);
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    ipServer = c.getString(0);
                    PortaServer = c.getInt(1);
                }
                if (ipServer == BuildConfig.FLAVOR || PortaServer == 0) {
                    ipServer = "192.168.1.2";
                    PortaServer = 4444;
                }
                publishProgress(new String[]{"Comunicazione con il server..."});
                networkresult r = SendCmd(datiXml, ipServer, PortaServer);
                Ret.result = r.result;
                if (r.result != 0) {
                    Ret.errMesg = r.errMesg;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("StartDbSincTask:", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return Ret;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            try {
                pd.setContent(values[0]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("onProgressUpdate:", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(genericresult result) {
            try {
                if (result.result != 0) {
                    crea_snackbar("result !=0 " + result.errMesg, true);
                } else if (result.errMesg.compareTo(BuildConfig.FLAVOR) != 0) {
                    crea_snackbar("Errore  " + result.errMesg, true);
                } else {
                    crea_snackbar("il terminale è stato correttamente registrato.", true);
                }
                //pd.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

In Sink Task starts the method that handles the data received: SendCmd

```
private networkresult SendCmd(String datiDaInviare, String Sever, int PortaTCP) {
networkresult Ret = new networkresult(0, BuildConfig.FLAVOR, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
try {
    if (datiDaInviare == BuildConfig.FLAVOR) {
        Ret.result = -1;
        Ret.errMesg = "Nessun ID terminale rilevato.";
        Log.e("ERRORE", "Nesun ID terminale rilevato SendCmd");
    } else {
        genericresult r = new genericresult(0,null,BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
        Socket nsocket = null;
        genericresult novarum_risto_vrordina_genericresult = new genericresult(0, null, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
        int index = 0;
        while (index < 4) {
            r = CollegaAlServer(Sever, PortaTCP, 1000);
            Log.e("SendCmd","é stato appena avviato il metodo CollegaAlServer");
            Log.e("r result", ""+r.result);
            if (r.result == 0) {
                int length;
                nsocket = (Socket)r.Dati;
                SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(Sever, PortaTCP);
                nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 1000);
                Log.e("SendCmd","Avviata la connessione dentro all'if");
                nsocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                InputStream nis = nsocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
                ArrayList<Byte> dati = new ArrayList();
                dati.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) 95));
                byte[] len = TLVParser.intToByteArray(datiDaInviare.length());
                TLVParser.reverse(len);
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    length = len.length;
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    dati.add(Byte.valueOf(len[i]));
                    i++;
                }
                byte[] contenuto = datiDaInviare.getBytes("UTF-8");
                i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    length = contenuto.length;
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    dati.add(Byte.valueOf(contenuto[i]));
                    i++;
                }
                byte[] datatosend = new byte[dati.size()];
                for (i = 0; i < dati.size(); i++) {
                    datatosend[i] = ((Byte) dati.get(i)).byteValue();
                }
                nos.write(datatosend);
                byte[] ret = TLVParser.readTLV(nis, 95);
                if (ret == null) {
                    Ret.result = -1;
                    Ret.errMesg = "Errore comunicazione con il server";
                    Log.e("ERRORE", "ERRORE Comunicazione con il server SendCmd");
                } else {
                    Ret.Dati = new String(ret);
                    if (Ret.Dati.compareTo("OK") != 0) {
                        Ret.result = -1;
                        Ret.errMesg = Ret.Dati;
                    }
                }
                if (nsocket != null) {
                    nsocket.close();
                }
                if (r.result != 0) {
                    Ret.result = -1;
                    Ret.errMesg = "Errore collegamento 2 con il server";
                    Log.e("ERRORE","Errore collegamento con il server 2 SendCmd");
                }
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (nsocket != null) {
            nsocket.close();
        }
        if (r.result != 0) {
            Ret.result = -1;
            Ret.errMesg = "Errore collegamento 3 con il server";
            Log.e("ERRORE", "Errore collegamento con il server 3 SendCmd");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Ret.result = -1;
    Ret.errMesg = e.getMessage();
}
return Ret;
```

}

Inside the method SendCmd method is called Connect To Server connecting to the server:

```
private genericresult CollegaAlServer(String Sever, int PortaTCP, int timeout) {
    genericresult ret = new genericresult(0, null, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
    try {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(Sever, PortaTCP);
        Socket nsocket = new Socket();
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
            if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
                ret.Dati = nsocket;
                Log.e("CollegaAlServer","Il socket si è connesso");
                break;
            }
            ret.result = -1;
            ret.errMesg = "Errore collegamento con il server";
            Log.e("ERRORE","Errore collegamento con il serer, private CollgaAlServer");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret.result = -1;
        ret.errMesg = e.getMessage();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Use two classes: network and result generic result

```
public class genericresult extends fresul {
    public Object Dati;

    public genericresult(int ret, Object dati, String errormsg) {
        super(ret, errormsg);
        this.Dati = dati;
    }
}

public class networkresult extends fresul {
    public String Dati;

    public networkresult(int ret, String dati, String errormsg) {
        super(ret, errormsg);
        this.Dati = dati;
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Or what is missing?

Class TLVParser:

```
public class TLVParser {
    public static String toUTF8(String isoString) {
        String utf8String = isoString;
        if (isoString == null || isoString.equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)) {
            return utf8String;
        }
        try {
            return new String(isoString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException is: " + e.getMessage());
            return isoString;
        }
    }

    public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[]{(byte) (value >>> 24), (byte) (value >>> 16), (byte) (value >>> 8), (byte) value};
    }

    public static void reverse(byte[] array) {
        if (array != null) {
            int j = array.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; j > i; i++) {
                byte tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] readTLV(InputStream tlv, int tag) {
        if (tlv == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid TLV");
        }
        byte[] vals = null;
        try {
            int c = tlv.read();
            if (c != 1 && c == tag) {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                c = tlv.read();
                if (c != -1) {
                    bb.put((byte) c);
                }
                c = tlv.read();
                if (c != -1) {
                    bb.put((byte) c);
                }
                c = tlv.read();
                if (c != -1) {
                    bb.put((byte) c);
                }
                c = tlv.read();
                if (c != -1) {
                    bb.put((byte) c);
                }
                int Len = bb.getInt(0);
                vals = new byte[Len];
                int Residuo = Len;
                int MaxRead = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT;
                if (AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT > Residuo) {
                    MaxRead = Residuo;
                }
                int offSet = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[Len];
                while (Residuo > 0) {
                    while (true) {
                        int len = tlv.read(bytes, 0, MaxRead);
                        if (len > 0) {
                            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, vals, offSet, len);
                            offSet += len;
                            Residuo -= len;
                            if (MaxRead > Residuo) {
                                MaxRead = Residuo;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errmsg = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vals;
    }

    public static byte[][] readTLV(String tlvHexString, int tag) throws Throwable {
        return readTLV(hexStringToByteArray(tlvHexString), tag);
    }

    public static byte[][] readTLV(byte[] tlv, int tag) throws Throwable {
        Throwable th;
        if (tlv == null || tlv.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid TLV");
        }
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        ByteArrayInputStream is = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(tlv);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int c = is2.read();
                    if (c == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else if (c == tag) {
                        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                        c = is2.read();
                        if (c != -1) {
                            bb.put((byte) c);
                        }
                        c = is2.read();
                        if (c != -1) {
                            bb.put((byte) c);
                        }
                        c = is2.read();
                        if (c != -1) {
                            bb.put((byte) c);
                        }
                        c = is2.read();
                        if (c != -1) {
                            bb.put((byte) c);
                        }
                        int Len = bb.getInt(0);
                        byte[] value = new byte[Len];
                        is2.read(value, 0, Len);
                        al.add(value);
                    }
                } catch (Throwable th2) {
                    th = th2;
                    is = is2;
                }
            }
            if (is2 != null) {
                try {
                    is2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            byte[][] vals = new byte[al.size()][];
            al.toArray(vals);
            return vals;
        } catch (Throwable th3) {
            th = th3;
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                }
            }
            throw th;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[(len / 2)];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b, int offset) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            value += (b[i + offset] & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) << ((3 - i) * 8);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

**This is my LogCat : **

```
01-13 10:37:09.738 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Already connected
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:813)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at com.edsoft.vrcomande2.ConfigurazioniActivity.SendCmd(ConfigurazioniActivity.java:351)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at com.edsoft.vrcomande2.ConfigurazioniActivity.access$600(ConfigurazioniActivity.java:48)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at com.edsoft.vrcomande2.ConfigurazioniActivity$SincTask.doInBackground(ConfigurazioniActivity.java:264)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at com.edsoft.vrcomande2.ConfigurazioniActivity$SincTask.doInBackground(ConfigurazioniActivity.java:240)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-13 10:37:09.743 14592-17524/com.edsoft.vrcomande2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Have you given internet permission in your android manifest ?

Comment: What is 'a local server'? If your problem is only establishing a connection then why post all that code? Don't expect us 'to figer it out'! You should do that and tell us the problems, errors, exceptions and so.

Comment: 'can not connect to a server, the code I get this error: Required java.net.Socket found java.lang.Object'. That looks more like a compile time error. This has nothing to do with not being able to establish a connection. Your app does not even exist or run.

Comment: @greenapps         That's right, I can not even fill out the application because of this error. I have included only the code that is called in the connection process so that you can be absent in helping aggevolati. The error I receive in the method SendCmd this command: nsocket = r.Dati;

The local server is a program resident on a computer which manages the data and everything else
I state that this code is run into another application, then I do not know what I can do to solve.

Comment: Yes you added the logcat. Now please first tell you which error/exception you get and at which codeline. Learn to read the LogCat. All is in it.

Comment: @greenapps I checked the manifest and I added this permit:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>          I started the application but I get the same error just in logcat eventually I see this error:    W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.92 (port 4444) after 1000ms      E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: Well that is a different exception isn't it? You use an emulator or a real device?

Comment: @greenapps Yes it is another exception, use more real devices

Comment: Are they in the same WLAN as the server? If so then check the firewall for preventing connections. Switch it off for a while. Which ip do you use?

Comment: Both the server and the client are on the same network, the firewall should not create problems because the original application can not connect to the server.
I think the server can log in because the first connection gives me a message saying: result! = Already connected but does not send data to the server. I think you make a connection without sending data in logcat giving that message: sendUserActionEvent () MView == null

Comment: @greenapps Add the new LogCat With the new controls in the log, to check the progress

Comment: Sorry, where are you talking about?

Comment: @greenapps I did not understand what you're asking

Comment: @greenapps Need other methods to help me?

Comment: You have not told why you posted a new logcat. You did not tell which error or exection you have now. Or where your probliem lies. So i will not look in the logcat. You should do that and tell us which problems you see.

Comment: @greenapps I just did a test, in Logcat message appears saying that the connection with the socket is already open, so do not proceed to check the data received and above all do not send anything to the server.
I added the class TLVParser is this class which controls the data received, would not that have something wrong here.

Comment: `connection with the socket is already open`. Cannot you start with mentioning the correct message?

Comment: @greenapps the message is :  result !=0 Already  connected

Comment: No. The message is `java.net.SocketException: Already connected`. And you are also supposed to comment on that your self first.

Comment: @greenapps What do you advise me to do?

Comment: You are supposed to comment on that exception first.

Comment: @greenapps Should I put a log in the exception? how can I do? how can I manage it?

Comment: Sorry, but if you do not react on my suggestions all stops.

Comment: @greenapps I'm trying to figure out what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at compile time and has nothing to do with servers or trying to connect to a server. The only thing you had to post to reproduce your error is

```
public class genericresult extends fresul {
public Object Dati;

public genericresult(int ret, Object dati, String errormsg) {
    super(ret, errormsg);
    this.Dati = dati;
}
}
```

And then the statements:

```
genericresult r = new genericresult(0, null, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);

Socket nsocket = r.Dati;
```

That would give you your error message `Required java.net.Socket found java.lang.Object`.

So Dati is not a Socket instance.

Something else:

```
       for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
            if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
                ret.Dati = nsocket;
                break;
            }
            ret.result = -1;
            ret.errMesg = "Errore collegamento con il server";
        }
```

It makes no sense to make a loop to try that five times. One time would be enough. Then set a longer timeout.

Moreover if the first try times out you already set a result value and an error message value which you do not remove or change when the second connect goes ok.

Comment: The problem was solved by inserting the error by replacing socket = r.Dati; with nsocket = (Socket) r.Dati;    I can not connect, I receive this message: result !=0 Errore collegamento con il server.      How can I fix?

Comment: I ad the LogCat on the question

Comment: `Errore collegamento con il server.`. Well that is your own error. That does not tell us very much. Look at your own code. When are you displaying the error? And where did you put it in?  That is when r.result != 0;. Now go back and find out why that is 0. You can do that yourself.  Advice: Don't put the same error mesage in that string the whole time because then you do not know which of the one it is.